# vue application best practice/pattern to display data with people-friendly label?

Tags: vue.js, design-patterns

A high-level vue application question:

A little background:

- small team, still learning vue
- creating a new large reasonably complex vue app from scratch
- vue-cli scaffolded (vue 2, veux, router, i118n, bootstrapVue)
- there are many different application entities – e.g. "user", “product”, etc.
- there are many of each item, and each has a data record (from a db) that includes a number of boolean fields such as "active", “enabled”,  “is_sensitive”.
- item data displays in many different contexts, including: search results, table lists (e.g. browse), individual landing views for each (an item detail page), as well as ancillary lists (e.g. “A related item:”

**The key problem:

In every display situation, the boolean values should to be translated from machine-friendly to people-friendly terminology.**

The appropriate human-friendly term depends on the field itself (so there is no single translation for all fields).

Example:
Machine-friendly data:

```
[
    {
        name: “Megaphone”,
        is_embarrassing: false,
        active: false,
    },
    {
        name: “Wankel Rotary Engine”,
        is_embarrassing: true,
        active: true,
    },
]
```

Human-friendly list:

```
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Name                 | Active?  | Embarrassing?       |
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Megaphone            | Inactive | Not embarassing     |
| Wankel Rotary Engine | Active   | Item is Embarassing |
+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

**The key question:

What is the best way to solve this in a scalable, efficient, elegant, sensible way?**

I have thought of a couple of options…neither of these feel scalable nor elegant,
and are brittle.

(1) sequence of in-line v-if conditions within the component view template

```html
    <p v-if=“item.property.is_embarrassing">
        Item is Embarrassing
    </p>
    <p v-else>
        Not embarassing
    </p>
```

(2) computed properties in the component

```html
    <p>
        {{ detailsPropertyEmbarrassing }}
    </p>
```

```js
    detailsPropertyEmbarrassing() {
        return item.property.is_embarrassing ? “Item is Embarrassing : “Not Embarrassing”;
    },
```

I have also been noodling over the idea of some sort of Map that is imported along with the data and used to get the right labels, but I haven’t completely worked that out yet.

What is a solution for transforming data fields to people-friendly labels across an entire application, for a variety of different display situations?

(Side note: I may also need to transform the field in other ways, such as truncating length…)

And is there a way to establish this globally in the app in a manner that is scalable, both technically and organizationally,
so that new components can display as desired, near-automatically?

This seems like a basic fundamental need in any app of size, not just vue,
so I feel like this has been/has to have been solved before, but either I cannot find the right research keywords or am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the VueComponent as a ViewModel (or Controller if you like MVC). It's indented purpose is to fetch information from the model (backend) and transform it to something that your view can use.

Thus, the change from a boolean to a string should be done in the VueComponent and not in the view.

In your view component, declare something like `myItems = []`. When you fetch it, traverse the result:

```js
backendResult.forEach(item => {
   this.myItems.push({
      name: item.Name,
      embarrassing: item.IsEmbarrassing ? "Oh yes!" : "No"
   });
```

Then the view is simplified:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in myItems">
            <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.embarrassing}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Another solution is to use [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) which requires no modification of the vue component and just a small change of the view:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in myItems">
            <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.isEmbarrassing|embarrassing}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice the `|embarrassing` part in the view. It uses a filter defined as:

```js
Vue.filter('filter', function (value) {
  if (!value) return 'not embarrassing'
  return 'embarrassing';
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts. I should probably do something more like the first choice. I could probably do that translation in the api method.

It wasn't clear to me yet when I'd want to use filters, but your point seems like a good option. I presume that filters could be defined as a mixin?

Comment: Filters are typically declared/imported in your entry javascript and can be used in any of your vue components.